# Cordova plugin network information is not working in Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I have already tried below things.

Added this modules.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

Also added `Network` in my `app.module.ts`

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

@NgModule({
 ...
 providers: [Network]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Have used inside `app.component.ts` like this :

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

constructor(platform: Platform, private network: Network) {        
    platform.ready().then(() => {

    let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network was disconnected !!');
    });

    let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network connected!');
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
          console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
        }
      }, 3000);
    });
  });    
}
```

I am getting nothing in console.

> The problem is When my application initialize the console is not triggered, also i have trying to console `network`, but i got empty `{}`.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-olizr8)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your problem may be console logging and not the network plugin?  Have you tried throwing in `alert('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!')` in place of the console log?

Comment: @BRass, Thanks for your help, but it also not woking.

Answer (score 0):

This only work on realDevices or simulator

```
constructor(private network: Network) {

    this.network_check();

  }


  network_check() {

        if (this.network.type === 'WIFI' || 'CELL_3G' || 'CELL_4G') {

          let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {


           alert("Disconnected");

          });
        }
      }
```